# How to rotate a function by a desired angle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How to rotate a function by the desired angle (for instance, 30 degrees)?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, sin

def g(y):
    return exp(-y)*sin(4*y)

y = np.linspace(0, 1.8, 501)
values = g(y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))

plt.plot(y, values)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Here is a duplicate [from math.exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17250/500346).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the cosine and sine of the angle, you can create a rotation matrix. Multiplying each point (`y, g(y)`) with that matrix create a rotation around `0,0`.

Here is some Python/numpy code to illustrate how everything could work together:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def g(y):
    return np.exp(-y) * np.sin(4 * y)

y = np.linspace(0, 1.8, 501)
values = g(y)

theta = np.radians(30)
c, s = np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)
rot_matrix = np.array(((c, s), (-s, c)))
xy = np.array([y, values]).T @ rot_matrix

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))

plt.plot(y, values)
plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1])
plt.axis('equal')  # so angles on the screen look like the real angles
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To rotate around another point, first subtract the rotation center, do the rotation and then add it again:

```py
center = np.array([0.9, 0])
xy = (np.array([y, values]).T - center) @ rot_matrix + center
```